# how can i debug Scrapy python <DELIM '#' at 0> Error?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

***<DELIM '#' at 0> Error***

response.css("#\39  > div > div:nth-child(1)").getall()
this code i wrote it

**SelectorSyntaxError: Expected selector, got <DELIM '#' at 0>**
this Error !!!

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character. If you must use this in a string, make it a raw string:

```
response.css(r"#\39 > div > div:nth-child(1)").getall()
```

Either way, `"#\39 > div > div:nth-child(1)"` is not a valid CSS selector. You may want to review it.